# Python: how to display dynamically changing graph matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, graph

I want to plot line graph row my row & I want the previous line to be updated by the next line (on the same frame).
Here's the example of the input:

[image]

Here's the code that I have:

```
def openB():
bmFile = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r',
                                    filetypes=(("CSV file", "*.csv"), ("All files", "*.*")),
                                    title="Select a CSV file")

bmFile2 = pd.read_csv(bmFile, header=[2])

selectCol = bmFile2.iloc[0:,3:]

selectCol.T.plot()
plt.show()
```

I want to plot each row, that's why I am using Transpose method on selectCol.

In order to plot row by row (dynamically changing), what function should I do?
FuncAnimation or for loop (range)?
and How?

Thank you.
Greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `plt.clf` and `plt.draw` to plot it dynamically.

As follows for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file = np.random.normal(5,5,(1000,100))

for row in file:
    plt.clf() # Clear the current figure
    
    plt.plot(row) # Calculate and plot all you want

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1) # Has to pause for a non zero time

plt.show() # When all is done
```

PS: `ax.clear()` will clear the axis while `plt.clf()` will clear the entire figure.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to dynamically plot each row:

```
with open('file.csv','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for line in lines:
    y = line.split(',')[2:]
    x = np.linspace(0,1,num=len(y))
    plt.plot(x,y)
```

I know this doesn't animate, but I it helps the dynamic issue.